# How does nodejs-redis(&connect-redis) deal with sync and async?

Tags: node.js, redis

I used **connect-redis** for my session store, and when I use `req.session`, it seems all the operations on it are **synchronized**, it's like operating on ordinary Javascript variables, the code obey the order. but I check the [source code](https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis/blob/master/lib/connect-redis.js), which uses the asynchronized way, so I wonder why the `req.session` acts like that.

Another question is that if I have multiple **redis** queries,

```
client.sadd('test', 1);
client.del('test');
client.sadd('test', 2);
client.sadd('test', 3);
```

no matter where I put the **del** operation, the results always the same. I thought these queries might be run in any order right? since they all asynchronized called, so the results I expected should be different every time.

Thanks for you help

Comment: What do you mean by 'result is always right'. If it's right then what's the problem?

Comment: sorry that I am not clear, because I suppose they run in random order because of the asynchronize, so the results might be different every time, but the results are the same every time and they are right

Answer (score 2):

The fact that roundtrips to the Redis server are managed asynchronously does not mean the queries will be sent in random order.

Redis (and therefore most Redis client libraries) supports [pipelining](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining), generally used to optimize the number of roundtrips. The idea is to send multiple queries, and then wait for the replies. The order is critical, because it is used by the client to match queries and replies.

Node.js is very well suited to support this kind of mechanisms. Matt Ranney's [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) client supports pipelining in a transparent way. Provided the same client object is used, all the queries will be serialized and executed in order.

In your example, it is normal the queries are always executed in the same order. You can check this point by using the [monitor](http://redis.io/commands/monitor) command to display the flow of queries sent to Redis.

Now, it is important the last query of the pipeline is associated with a callback, otherwise your program will never know when the last query is complete.